# JqueryMobile Listview remove old values

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am calling the following code in .ajax call to webservice and getting the values into "public_tweets". The code works fine and also populates the data into listview. The problem is if I call this piece of code twice(like on button click), the values in the listview which were populated before remains and a new group of listview is addedd. How to display listview only for the recent search ...????. Apprecite all the help...!!!!

```
 $("#placeholder").after('<ul id="unfinshed" data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-inset="true"></ul>');
       // $('#unfinshed').empty();
        for (var x = 0; x < public_tweets.length; x++) {
            var txt = public_tweets[x];
            $('<li><a href="#">' + txt.Name + '</a>' +
            '<ul data-theme="c" data-inset="true">' +
            '<li> ' + txt.Phone + '</li>' +
            '<li> ' + txt.Email + '</li>' +
            '<li> ' + txt.City + '</li>' +
            '<li> ' + txt.State + '</li>' +
            '<li> ' + txt.Country + '</li>' +
            '</ul>' +
            '</li>').appendTo("#unfinshed");

        }
        $("#unfinshed").page();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#unfinshed").page('refresh', true);
```

or

```
$("#unfinshed").page('refresh');
```